# Distance between unit sphere of hilbert space and closed subspace

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $H$ Hilbert space and $M\subsetneq H$ a closed subspace.

> Prove there exists $x\in S_H$ s.t. $d(x,S_M)=\sqrt2$

where $S_H,S_M$ denote the unit spheres and $d(x,S_M):=\inf_{y\in S_M} ||x-y||$

My try:

I know that Hilbert spaces attain their distance from closed subspaces, i.e. if $L\subseteq H$ a closed subspace and $x\in H$ there exists $y\in L$ satisfying $d(x,L)=||x-y||$.

I'm also aware of Reisz Lemma.

How can I use those to prove the said result?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The proof used in riesz's Theomre can be adapted for general closed convex sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $M$ is a proper closed subspace, its [orthogonal complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_complement#Inner_product_spaces) is non-zero. Let $x$ be a unit vector orthogonal to $M.$ Then, by Pythagoras' theorem, $\|x-y\|=\sqrt2$ for all $y\in S_M,$ so $d(x,S_M)=\sqrt2.$

Comment: Why can we necessarily find orthogonal vector?

Comment: $M^\perp\ne\{0\}$ because $M$ is closed and $\ne H.$

Comment: Is this a well known proposition?

Comment: Yes, see [Orthogonal complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_complement#Inner_product_spaces)